# Messenger bot - Sample code

Tags: node.js, bots, facebook-messenger

I am trying to create a bot. Using this project. My setup is as follows:

Amazon EC2 instance. I created a `sub-domain.domain.com` I have added the ssl certifications. I have pointed the sub-domain to the `/var/www/sub-domain/`

I have installed the unzip and installed the project in `/var/www/sub-domain/project/` I have configured the project and correctly run it:

Node app is running on port 5000

If I access `http://sub-domain.domain.com:5000` I access to the projects public index. I understand that means the port is open and the node app works.

Now when I am trying to configure in facebook my webhook I dont understand what url callbak to use. From what I understand in the configuration the server url whould be `https://sub-domain.domain.com` and the configuration should work. but it doesnt.

What url should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback URL should be your actual file where facebook would send user data. Like if you were using PHP, you'd say: `http://yourhost/chatbot.php`. Currently, webhook would be the URL on which your node app is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Your webhook needs to an accessible URL. I don't know which sample code you used, but my guess is that with your current set up you should use `http://sub-domain.domain.com:5000/webhook`.

You can use Apache or Nginx to make it accessible on `http://sub-domain.domain.com/webhook` (port 80) with `ProxyPass`/`proxy_pass` directives.

> I have installed the unzip and installed the project in /var/www/sub-domain/project/ [...] I access to the projects public index

The Javascript files of your project don't need to and *should* not be accessible to the public, as they may contain your application's secret IDs and tokens.